# How to see MSBuild output generated in project load time?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I've noticed that when Visual Studio 2012 loads/initializes projects (when opening a solution or when changing platforms/configurations), it may execute some MSBuild targets - those that are listed as `InitialTargets` (it doesn't always do that - sometimes it waits until you actually build it; I can't figure out when exactly, but that's a different question).

Anyway, these targets may generate some output in the form of MSBuild messages. If the targets were being run as part of a build, these messages would go to the output window of Visual Studio (and perhaps a log file). These "load-time targets", though, do not seem to send their output to the output window.

How can I see or log the output of MSBuild targets which execute outside of build time, and specifically in initialization time?

Comment: I was/am looking for an extension point "loading project in VS", and i've tested `InitialTargets`. When i put a warning in an initial target, it is shown in the error window (after starting VS, not after explicitly building). As you state, `InitialTargets` is not executed for all of the projects, only for some. Also, `<Message Importance="High" Text=".."/>` is nowhere to be found (as you already stated). I'm using VS2013 update 2.

Answer (score 0):

The best [information source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/11/22/495322.aspx) from the MSBuild team at Microsoft I could find is dated (2005), but may still be actual if no one could come up with fresher information:

> The **project load** logger is used when projects are opened. It discards all messages logged while the project is opened, puts warnings in the error list, and displays any errors in a message box to the user. The errors displayed are quite detailed and useful in helping diagnose project file formatting issues.